# Node.JS Crypto Cipher/Decipher not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, cryptography

Here is the code:

```
    var kk = JSON.stringify(object);
    console.log(kk);
    var kk1 = encrypt(kk);
    console.log(kk1)
    var kk2 = decrypt(kk1);
    console.log(kk2)
    this.write(encrypt(kk))
```

Functions:

```
var encrypt = function (data) {
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ecb', password)
    cipher.update(data, 'utf8')
    return cipher.final('hex')
}
var decrypt = function (data) {
    var cipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ecb', password)
    cipher.update(data, 'hex')
    return cipher.final('utf8')
}
```

console message:

```
{"action":"ping","ping":30989}
4613a3a8719c921eed61e19b7480de9c
,"ping":30989}
```

Why decrypting doesn't result into initial string?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`.update()`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/crypto.html#crypto_cipher_update_data_input_encoding_output_encoding) returns partially ciphered/deciphered content and you're immediately discarding that data. You're also missing the output encoding for `.update()` that matches what you're using in `.final()`. Try this:

```
function encrypt(data) {
  var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ecb', password);
  return cipher.update(data, 'utf8', 'hex') + cipher.final('hex');
}

function decrypt(data) {
  var cipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ecb', password);
  return cipher.update(data, 'hex', 'utf8') + cipher.final('utf8');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that `.update()` and `.final()` are [mentioned to be legacy methods in the crypto module](http://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_class_cipher), I thought I'd provide a second way. Cipher objects are [streams](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html), so you can do:

```
function encrypt(data) {
    var text = JSON.stringify(data);
    var textBuffer = new Buffer(text, 'utf8');
    var cipher = crypto.createCipher('aes-256-ecb', password);
    cipher.write(textBuffer);
    cipher.end();
    return cipher.read().toString('hex');
}

function decrypt(hexString) {
    var hexBuffer = new Buffer(hexString, 'hex');
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipher('aes-256-ecb', password);
    decipher.write(hexBuffer);
    decipher.end();
    var data = decipher.read().toString('utf8');
    return JSON.parse(data);
}
```

I added JSON.stringify and parse to handle numbers/objects.